# How to make zsh word navigation/deletion work like Vim

Tags: text, zsh

I am using `zsh` and I want word navigation/deletion to work exactly how it does in Vim to suit my muscle memory.

In Vim, given the text `foo ./bar baz-bob`, each forward navigation starting from the first character plays out like so:

```
foo ./bar baz-bob
^   ^ ^   ^  ^^
```

In default zsh, it plays out like so:

```
foo ./bar baz-bob
^   ^     ^      ^
```

I have managed to achieve some success using `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\/-]}`. As I understand it, this works by removing the `/` and `-` chars from `WORDCHARS`. `WORDCHARS` is a string of characters which are also part of a word.

```
foo ./bar baz-bob
^   ^ ^   ^   ^  ^
```

Note: I am aware of zsh's vi mode, but I would prefer to configure zsh's default mode to behave this way.

Comment: I think all you need is `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\/.-]}`

Comment: I just tested this and it doesn't help to solve my problem. The cursor still does not stop on the `-` like in vim, and what's more, it doesn't stop on the `.` anymore.

Comment: I cant see how `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\/]}` would remove the `-` character.  Perhaps you want `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\/-]}` ?

Comment: Sorry, my original post was supposed to show that. I will update now.

Answer (score 1):

For newest MacOS Sierra + iTerm2 + oh-my-zsh, if I continuously press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> after typing `cd /usr/local/share/gobject-introspection-1.0`, then the story becomes like :

```
cd /usr/local/share/gobject-introspection-1.0
cd /usr/local/share/gobject-introspection-1.
cd /usr/local/share/gobject-introspection-
cd /usr/local/share/gobject-
cd /usr/local/share/
cd /usr/local/
```

I do not have any key-binding or other profile files. I dislike too much files. Here is my `.zshrc` needed part :

```
...
    bindkey -e
    bindkey '^[[1;9C' forward-word
    bindkey '^[[1;9D' backward-word
...
```

If the above does not work or you not like then you can try this on `~/.zshrc` :

```
WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'
```

or :

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

or ([I found the below a gist which referred here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2001/msg00870.html)) :

```
tcsh-backward-delete-word () {
  local WORDCHARS="${WORDCHARS:s#/#}"
  zle backward-delete-word
}
bindkey '^W' tcsh-backward-delete-word
```

Comment: This does not provide word navigation/deletion like in Vim, as described in my original post. Please test your method with the examples I posted above, and you will see the result is not as desired.

Comment: Sadly that is happening with me! Many are saying that not happening after update of ZSH. Please search Github with key phrases, you'll possibly find victims like you who somehow fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48577/modifying-the-zsh-shell-word-split)? You can re-export the WORDCHARS environment variable without the dash.

Comment: Hi yes, I am using the shortcut version recommended in that post, but this does not solve my question as above. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48577/modifying-the-zsh-shell-word-split#comment67851_48589